# How to get User properties by URL and then use it as variable on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters

I want to get the **city properties : 918** by using `req.params.userMosque` for this URL `'/shalat/:userMosque'`, so I can use it as `var city` to customize my API url request as you can see. but it didn't works somehow. i have this user from database :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b99056c60ba8e263fe6aff6"),
  "name" : "Ian",
  "email" : "tes@gmail.com",
  "mosque" : "al hijrah",
  "city" : "918", 
  "date" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:24:12.121Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

and i have this Express code below:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

// Load Info Model
require('../models/Info');
const Info = mongoose.model('info');

// Load Info Model
require('../models/User');
const User = mongoose.model('users');


router.get('/shalat/:userMosque', (req, res) => {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var city = ?


if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

request('https://api.banghasan.com/sholat/format/json/jadwal/kota/'+ city +'/tanggal/' + yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render('mosques/shalat',{data:data});
        console.log(data);
       }
   });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I tried research on express and request, but I still can't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/shalat/:userMosque', (req, res) => {
  var userMosque = req.params.userMosque;
  userMosque = JSON.parse(userMosque)
  var city = userMosque.city
  console.log(city)
  res.send(city)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Comment: Please let me know you still facing problem.

Comment: thanks, gonna try this first .will let you know if this works

Comment: i get this error "Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0"

Comment: I edited the above Answer and it's working for me with http://localhost:3000/shalat/{"city":"Hello"}

Comment: Answers which explain their code generally get more upvotes than those which simply give code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for your feedback, i will try to follow. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, i still get this "Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0". 

btw this is the API url result if my code works :
https://api.banghasan.com/sholat/format/json/jadwal/kota/918/tanggal/2018-09-13

Comment: I understood your expected output url, Are you still using router to route your requests? Are you tried with simple standalone application with my code?

Comment: Are you passing {"_id" : ObjectId("5b99056c60ba8e263fe6aff6"), "date" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:24:12.121Z")} with your URL, This two fields might cause SyntaxError: Unexpected token issue.

Comment: yes i use router since i try it directly in my code.

Comment: btw i just tried your code with new application and i still get the same error somehow.

Comment: Are you passing **"date" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:24:12.121Z")** & **"_id" : ObjectId("5b99056c60ba8e263fe6aff6")** with your request URL?

Comment: yes i didn't use that two field cuz i only use "mosque" : "al hijrah" to get the "city" : "918"

Comment: Can you please share your URL with dummy domain?

Comment: If this is your URL then don't need to parse as json **userMosque = JSON.parse(userMosque)** this line should cause "Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Because you just passing query as string, If you passing URL like **localhost:1000/mosque/shalat/{"city":"Hello"}** this then you need to parse.

Comment: from that link i got "al hijrah" as string.
but the city remain undefined
 
'var userMosque = req.params.userMosque;
  var city = userMosque.city
  console.log(city)'

Comment: Then your URL should be like this **localhost:1000/mosque/shalat/{"city":"Your city", "any": "al hijrah"}**, Then you should include JSON.parse line, after that you can get **var city = userMosque.city** & **var any = userMosque.any //i.e al hijrah**

Comment: @Akbar, Sounds great! Happy coding!